# How to unlock when the channel is blocked?

Tags: go

`sendTo` is a function that can be called as goroutine at different places:

```golang
func (s *Sender) sendTo() {
    for {
        s.Lock()
        if s.next == len(s.msgs) {
            s.Unlock()
            break
        }
        // prepare message...
        msg := s.msgs[s.next]
        s.next++
        s.ch <- msg
        s.Unlock()
    }
}
```

Members of `s` can be accessed in different goroutine (`s.ch` only be used in `sendTo`), so there is a lock to protect them. However, `s.ch` might be full so that `sendTo` will hold the lock for a long time. To solve this problem, I modify the code to:

```
func (s *Sender) sendTo() {
    for {
        s.Lock()
        if s.next == len(s.msgs) {
            s.Unlock()
            break
        }
        // prepare message...
        msg := s.msgs[s.next]
        s.next++
        s.Unlock()
        s.ch <- msg
    }
}
```

But this code can't ensure that the sequence of messages sended to `s.ch` is same as `s.msgs`. So I wonder if there is a way to block on channel then unlock (kind like condition variable).

Comment: If moving the lock loses your requirement of ordering, then unlocking that lock when it's inconvenient loses the same guarantees. According to your requirements, you need that lock around the read and send operations, so you _want_ it to block when it cannot send. Using a buffered channel should be sufficient to not block most of the time, but maintain your ordering when blocking is required.

Comment: @JimB thanks. For some reason, I can only use an unbuffered channel. Now I use a timer in select so that it will not hold the lock for too long. If timeouts, it sleeps for a while then retry.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) as I can't recall ever encountering a situation similar to yours. Which suggests you're not using the appropriate data structures and algorithm. Why is `s.msgs` even required? Why can't the code that appends to `s.msgs` just inject the message into `s.ch`? Also, it's usually a mistake to explicitly release the lock at the point where you're done with it. In code like yours you would normally have a `defer s.Unlock()` immediately after the `s.Lock()`.

Comment: Also, the lock should be acquired outside of the loop. You don't have multiple instances of `sendTo` running concurrently, do you? If yes, why? Again, the more I look at your function the more convinced I am that a different approach to your problem is warranted.

Comment: @ihnfsa, the fact that you are restricted to an unbuffered channel only reinforces my point. If you release the lock before sending, even after a timeout, you throw away the ordering guarantee. The unbuffered channel also means that a requirement is for the call to be synchronous with the receiver, which you are also breaking. You can either adhere to these requirements and block on the send, or they are not true requirements, and you can send in any order whenever possible.

Comment: @JimB You are correct, my current solution is unlocking after sending or timeout.

Comment: @KurtisRader Sorry, this is not original code, making the question unclear. Indeed, I have two index variables of `s.msgs`, one is `s.next`, indicating the next msg to be sent, the other one is `s.next <= s.submit < len(s.msgs)` which is used to indicate msgs ready to be sent. There are some goroutines may modifies the `s.submit` then `go s.sendTo()`.

Comment: @ihnfsa You're trying to fix code you didn't write? I don't see any way to fix the problem you've presented to us without a major rewrite using more appropriate data structures and algorithms, or at least more idiomatic Go code. At this point there is probably not much we can do to help you since your attempt to condense your situation into a minimal example is probably omitting to much important information.

Comment: @ihnfsa You wrote "There are some goroutines may modifies the s.submit then go s.sendTo()." You didn't mention `s.submit` prior to that comment so we have no idea what it is or its relevance. I'm really sorry, but unless you can rewrite your problem  it seems unlikely we will be able to help. I definitely don't see any way to "paper over" the behavior of the code you have shown us to behave as you desire.

Answer (score -1):

Although I'm not sure this code is good enough, how about this one?

```golang
func (s *Sender) sendTo() {
    for {
        s.lock.Lock()
        if s.next == len(s.msgs) {
            s.lock.Unlock()
            break
        }
        select {
            case s.ch <- s.msgs[s.next]:
                s.next++
            default:
        }
        s.lock.Unlock()
    }
}
```

I wrote the whole code here : https://go.dev/play/p/nWLeK6KdZg7

#### Reference

[Selecting from buffered vs non-buffered channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725744/selecting-from-buffered-vs-non-buffered-channel)

[How to know a buffered channel is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657207/how-to-know-a-buffered-channel-is-full)